# WebApi Service pinned to one Node

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I have a Stateless API Service in a Service Fabric solution, I want this service to be pinned to only one node of the two nodes that I have on my cluster.

How can I limit the API service to only live on one node?
The main problem is that each node has its own URL, and if the service jumps to the other node, the users can't connect to the API.

Thanks!

Comment: So, will you bear the risk not to be connected if the specific node is down? As a learner, I cannot say in detail but Service Fabric is designed not to make such a case as possible.

Comment: That's why API services are stateless and are placed on all the nodes in a cluster. If one node goes down, as Youngjae said, another one will server requests. This is how it is intended to work. Also, it looks strange that you need to connect to some particular node. I think that it is more common to have load balancer with a static URL that will redirect request to random nodes.

Comment: As far as I know, there's a limitation that you can't have more than one stateless webapi service. The service can only reside on one node, and is defined as a singleton. Therefore, no NLB will help me in this case, because the API can only reside on one node, and it's not active-active on multiple nodes. Hence my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure where the notion that you can't have more than one stateless Web API per cluster came from, but I suspect you are thinking of the local development machine.

In a production cluster you can host dozens of stateless Web API applications per node, and they can all share the same IP and port, and they can appear as one logical API surface.

In a local development cluster you can only have one instance of a Web API per cluster on the same IP and port because it's only one **physical** machine (your development box).

You resolve this by using the Application Parameters and publish profiles.

The publish profile for the cloud uses the setting -1, which means run on all nodes.

*ApplicationParameters\Cloud.xml* - [Parameter Name="TokenExchange_InstanceCount" Value="-1" /]

The publish profile for local development uses the setting 1, which means run on one node.

*ApplicationParameters\Local.xml* - [Parameter Name="TokenExchange_InstanceCount" Value="1" /]

If multiple APIs share the same IP and port you will need to differentiate applications by endpoint URL - for example, by adding additional segments to the URL

_serverUrl = $"{endpoint.Protocol}://+:{endpoint.Port}**/foo/bar/**";

Comment: It's still a singleton in Azure's [Fabrikam Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-web-reference-app/blob/master/ReferenceApp/WebReferenceApplication/ApplicationPackageRoot/ApplicationManifest.xml)

Comment: If you are referring to this line "<SingletonPartition />" - SingletonPartition defines that no partitioning is used.  This does not mean that only a single instance can run cluster wide. 


As I described - if you set InstanceCount to 1 the service would be deployed to 1 node, -1 all nodes.


https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2015/10/13/understanding-service-fabric-partitions/

Answer (score 0):

To answer the problem you're experiencing (as per your comment above), not responding to your original question (which is not recommended behaviour), you need to solve this in the Load balancer.
Add all your webapi node type  ip-addresses to the "Backend pools" of your Load balancer (one per node type).
Also, update your settings to deploy to multiple nodes as described above, setting instance count to -1.